# Checking is exit specific value in JSON object

Tags: java, json, dom

I had read about [How to check if a value/property exist in JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440522/how-to-check-if-a-value-property-exist-in-json-data). But this question was not satisfied for my problem. I used [net.sf.json.JSONObject](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/package-summary.html) for retrieving datas from my database.

Eg: I have a JSON Object as like...

```
{"a":"data", "b":"", "c":null, "d":2}
```

and I tested to check **e** value in this JSON.

```
            if (json.get("e") == null) {
                System.err.println("found in first case.");
            }
            else if (json.get("e").isNull()) {
                System.err.println("found in second case.");
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("All were skipped !");
            }
```

But the result doesn't come out as I expected (It always go to **else case**).I also would like to avoid **Null Pointer Exception**.  How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the solution for it !

```
    if(json.keySet().contains("e")) {
        System.out.println("BOOM");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not contain");
    }
```